# Double if in each jquery function

Tags: jquery

I am wondering why I have this code:

```
function setAddresses()
{
    $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
        var address = $(this).closest("td").next("td").next("td").text();
        var index = email.indexOf(address) == -1;
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true && index == -1 ) {
            email.push(address);
        }
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == false && index != -1) {
            email.slice(index, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

if I remove the second `if` all works fine (but obviously I need it), and if I keep it the page just doesn't work anymore..

All I want is that if a checkbox is selected and the element is not in the list I am going to add it, otherwise I want to remove it. When there isn't the second `if` all works fine, the array is populated and send the string over my textbox when I add the second `if` the textbox just is empty.

I would be glad if anyone can give me an answer on why it happens. Thank you

Comment: variable index is a boolean so your function email.slice should accept two ints. Good thing is to open developer tools in your browser and see if any errors come up.

Comment: index is boolean but you are using it in your  `email.slice(index, 1);` whereas string.slice takes 2 int arguments which are start index and end index.

Comment: Why do you need the global `email` array? You could grab all selected mail addresses at once if the state of a checkbox has changed ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t29xfw89/))